# CSS Transition acceleration

Tags: html, css

How can I change the acceleration of how fast a CSS transition speeds up and slows down.

For example, if I run this code:

```
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition-duration: 4s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>
```

it speeds up at a specific speed and starts slowing down at a specific speed.

How can I change the speed of how fast it speeds up and slows down (not the actual transition time, just the acceleration and deceleration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CSS3 transition-timing-function Property**

> The transition-timing-function property specifies the speed curve of
>   the transition effect.
>
> This property allows a transition effect to change speed over its
>   duration.

Syntax

`transition-timing-function: ease|linear|ease-in|ease-out|ease-in-out|cubic-bezier()|initial|inherit;`

[DOCUMENTATION HERE w/ Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function)

Answer (score 4):

For this, you need to use `transition-timing-function`.

From **[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)**

> The `transition-timing-function` property describes how the intermediate values used during a transition will be calculated. It allows for a transition to change speed over its duration. These effects are commonly called easing functions.

Now, you want to create a deceleration transition. For this, you need to look at position - time graph of deceleration and create a `cubic-bezier()` function similar to it.

[image]

Alter the values of the `cubic-bezier` function to suit your needs.

**Code Snippet** :

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.2,0.5,0.3,1);
}

div:hover {
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: sorry to resurrect, but is it possible to either a) find/define an exp. growth function for easing, or b) invert this cubic-bezier as like 1/x? basically to get the acceleration rate the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Set the `transition-timing-function` in your CSS:

```
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

Possible values: ease | linear | ease-in | ease-out | ease-in-out | cubic-bezier() | initial | inherit